# Animation partially completing when triggered by a UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, animation, uinavigationbar, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

In my app I have a `UINavigationBar` with a `UITapGestureRecognizer` that calls an animation method.

Sometimes—depending on how much like a swipe the tap is—the animation only partially completes and animates itself back to the starting position. I thought this might have to do with the animation starting before the gesture recognizer `.Ended` but adding a check didn't remove the problem.

It was not resolved with a check for `sender is UITapGestureRecognizer`.  What's going on here?

Comment: In the animation completion block check if the value `completed` is `true`. If you have `false`  you have something which blocks your animations.

Comment: I tried that and the value is always true.